# Postman changes all number values to 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman, backend

I've been looking around for a bit and can't seem to figure out why this happens.

I made a post request in postman, it runs it, intelliJ's console doesn't display an error, yet when printing out the object, it shows only the name has been inserted as I wrote it, the rest are 0's.

EDIT: numbers now come in, but foreign key "holdid" only returns as a null value

EDIT 2: Made it work, code changed to show working code

---

My Controller:

```
import com.example.tourdebackend.domain.model.Cykelrytter;
import com.example.tourdebackend.domain.service.CykelholdService;
import com.example.tourdebackend.domain.service.CykelrytterService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/tourdefrance")
public class CykelrytterController {

    private final CykelrytterService cykelrytterService;
    private final CykelholdService cykelholdService;

    @Autowired
    public CykelrytterController(CykelrytterService cykelrytterService, 
                    CykelholdService cykelholdService) {
        this.cykelrytterService = cykelrytterService;
        this.cykelholdService = cykelholdService;
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Cykelrytter> createCykelrytter(
                    @RequestBody Cykelrytter cykelrytter) {
        cykelrytterService.create(cykelrytter);
        System.out.println(cykelrytter);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My relevant service:

```
import com.example.tourdebackend.domain.model.Cykelrytter;
import com.example.tourdebackend.repository.CykelrytterRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CykelrytterService {

    private final CykelrytterRepository cykelrytterRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CykelrytterService(CykelrytterRepository cykelrytterRepository){
      this.cykelrytterRepository = cykelrytterRepository;
    }

    public void create (Cykelrytter cykelrytter) {
      cykelrytterRepository.save(cykelrytter);
    }

    public List<Cykelrytter> read() {
      return cykelrytterRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Cykelrytter> readById(int id) { return cykelrytterRepository.findById(id); }

    public Cykelrytter update(Cykelrytter cykelrytter){
      return cykelrytterRepository.save(cykelrytter);
    }

    public void delete(int id) { cykelrytterRepository.deleteById(id); }
}
```

Models:

```
package com.example.tourdebackend.domain.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
public class Cykelrytter {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "bjergpoint")
  @JsonProperty("bjergpoint")
  private int bjergPoint;
  @Column(name = "spurtpoint")
  @JsonProperty("spurtpoint")
  private int spurtPoint;
  @Column(name = "laptime")
  @JsonProperty("laptime")
  private double lapTime;

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "holdid", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Cykelhold cykelhold;

  public Cykelrytter() {

  }

  public Cykelrytter(int id, String name, int bjergPoint, int spurtPoint, double lapTime, Cykelhold cykelhold) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.bjergPoint = bjergPoint;
    this.spurtPoint = spurtPoint;
    this.lapTime = lapTime;
    this.cykelhold = cykelhold;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getBjergPoint() {
    return bjergPoint;
  }

  public void setBjergPoint(int bjergPoint) {
    this.bjergPoint = bjergPoint;
  }

  public int getSpurtPoint() {
    return spurtPoint;
  }

  public void setSpurtPoint(int spurtPoint) {
    this.spurtPoint = spurtPoint;
  }

  public double getLapTime() {
    return lapTime;
  }

  public void setLapTime(double lapTime) {
    this.lapTime = lapTime;
  }

  public Cykelhold getCykelhold() {
    return cykelhold;
  }

  public void setCykelhold(Cykelhold cykelhold) {
    this.cykelhold = cykelhold;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Cykelrytter{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", bjergPoint=" + bjergPoint +
            ", spurtPoint=" + spurtPoint +
            ", lapTime=" + lapTime +
            ", cykelhold=" + cykelhold +
            '}';
  }
}
```

```
package com.example.tourdebackend.domain.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Cykelhold {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "holdname")
  private String holdName;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  //@JsonBackReference
  private List<Cykelrytter> cykelrytters;

  public Cykelhold() {
  }

  public Cykelhold(int holdid, String holdName) {
    this.id = holdid;
    this.holdName = holdName;
  }

  public Cykelhold(int holdid, String holdName, List<Cykelrytter> cykelrytters) {
    this.id = holdid;
    this.holdName = holdName;
    this.cykelrytters = cykelrytters;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int holdid) {
    this.id = holdid;
  }

  public String getHoldName() {
    return holdName;
  }

  public void setHoldName(String holdName) {
    this.holdName = holdName;
  }

  public List<Cykelrytter> getCykelrytters() {
    return cykelrytters;
  }

  public void setCykelrytters(List<Cykelrytter> cykelrytters) {
    this.cykelrytters = cykelrytters;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Cykelhold{" +
        "id=" + id +
        ", holdName='" + holdName + '\'' +
        ", cykelrytters=" + cykelrytters +
        '}';
  }
}
```

My postman request:

```
{
    "bjergpoint": 5,
    "laptime": 52.02,
    "cykelhold":{
        "id": 2
    },
    "name": "kurt",
    "spurtpoint": 5
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You really should avoid using `@Entity` as DTOs in your controller, you will get plenty of extra work to get around DB constraints later on.

Answer (score 2):

For JSON deserialization, Jackson is case sensitive to find the Java fields for each of the fields in the JSON body. In your case, the Java field names are not the same as the JSON field names. You either have to rename them in one of the sides, or add the `JsonProperty` annotation to tell Jackson, what the field is called in the JSON body.

Example:

```
@Column(name = "bjergpoint")
@JsonProperty("bjergpoint")
private int bjergPoint;
```

Comment: Thank you very much that seems to have fixed several of my issues !

I do have another issue with my foreign key'd value returning as 0 still though, any idea what a fix for that could be ?

EDIT: Postman also refuses to send in data now with a 400 error "bad request", presumably coming from the @JsonProperty being written wrong